# My Chrome extension isn't working and I have fixed all errors

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I wanted to make a simple notes app that adds a note on the page of any website. I have been testing it for a while and im getting no errors anymore but whenever I click the button "open note" it doesnt do anything.

manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "Notepad Extension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "A simple notepad extension for Chrome",
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab"
  ],
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_icon": {
      "16": "logo.png"
    }
  },
  "icons": {
    "16": "logo.png"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["content.js"]
    }
  ],
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  }
}
```

content.js

```
// Content script (content.js)
console.log("Content script loaded.");
console.log("Content script is running.");


function openNotepad() {
  const notepad = document.createElement("textarea");
  notepad.id = "notepad-extension";
  notepad.style.position = "fixed";
  notepad.style.top = "10px";
  notepad.style.left = "10px";
  notepad.style.width = "300px";
  notepad.style.height = "200px";
  notepad.style.zIndex = "9999";
  document.body.appendChild(notepad);
}
```

background.js

```
// Callback function for chrome.tabs.query
console.log("Background script is running.");

function handleTabs(tabs) {
  if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
    console.error(chrome.runtime.lastError);
    return;
  }

  // Find the active tab among the queried tabs
  const activeTab = tabs.find(tab => tab.active);

  if (activeTab) {
    chrome.scripting.executeScript({
      target: { tabId: activeTab.id },
      function: openNotepad,
    });
  } else {
    console.error("Active tab not found.");
  }
}

// Function to open the notepad in the content script
function openNotepad() {
  const notepad = document.createElement("textarea");
  notepad.id = "notepad-extension";
  notepad.style.position = "fixed";
  notepad.style.top = "10px";
  notepad.style.left = "10px";
  notepad.style.width = "300px";
  notepad.style.height = "200px";
  notepad.style.zIndex = "9999";
  document.body.appendChild(notepad);
}

// Add an event listener for when the extension icon is clicked
chrome.action.onClicked.addListener(function () {
  // Query all tabs to find the active tab
  chrome.tabs.query({}, handleTabs);
});
```

popup.js

```
// Callback function for chrome.tabs.query
function handleTabs(tabs) {
  if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
    console.error(chrome.runtime.lastError);
    return;
  }

  // Find the active tab among the queried tabs
  const activeTab = tabs.find(tab => tab.active);

  if (activeTab) {
    chrome.scripting.executeScript({
      target: { tabId: activeTab.id },
      function: openNotepad,
    });
  } else {
    console.error("Active tab not found.");
  }
}

// Function to open the notepad in the content script
function openNotepad() {
  const notepad = document.createElement("textarea");
  notepad.id = "notepad-extension";
  notepad.style.position = "fixed";
  notepad.style.top = "10px";
  notepad.style.left = "10px";
  notepad.style.width = "300px";
  notepad.style.height = "200px";
  notepad.style.zIndex = "9999";
  document.body.appendChild(notepad);
}

// Add an event listener for when the extension icon is clicked
chrome.action.onClicked.addListener(function () {
  // Query all tabs to find the active tab
  chrome.tabs.query({}, handleTabs);
});
```

and popup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Notepad Extension</title>
  <script src="popup.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <button id="openNotepadButton">Open Notepad</button>
</body>
</html>
```

I mostly did console.log and used chrome dev tools to find and fix previous errors but now I don't see any. I mean I do get this inspect views that says the service worker is inactive but I can't figure out why its not.

Comment: Remove `background` and `content_scripts` from manifest.json, remove background.js and content.js, remove `chrome.action.onClicked.addListener(function () {` line and the last `});` from popup.js.

Comment: you want me to remove backgorund.js and content.js altogether?

Comment: Of course. They are entirely redundant as you replicate all their functionality within popup.js.

Comment: same result, no errors, but no functionality

Comment: 1) Add `"scripting"` to `"permissions"`. 2) Note that the popup is a separate window so it has its own separate devtools: right-click inside the popup and select "inspect" in the menu.

Comment: still nothing, I'm not getting anything

Comment: Assuming you did everything correctly and reloaded the extension in chrome://extensions page, debug it in devtools as explained in my previous comment.

Comment: dev tools doesn't say there are any problems, it just doesn't work

Comment: That's why you need to actually debug it. Place breakpoints, step through the code, etc.